# Data won't save if metabox within conditional in admin. What am I missing?

Tags: customization, admin, metabox

What is wrong with this setup? Metaboxes inside this conditional will not get saved.

```
// Only shows for the admin front-page assigned page.
$front_page_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
$post_id = (empty($_GET['post'])) ? NULL : $_GET['post'];

if (is_admin() && $front_page_id == $post_id) {
    ........
}
```

*Background:* The idea of this setup is to have only on the static front page(Settings -> Reading) meta fields for the user to upload images that will be use on the slider.

Comment: There is not enough context. Where is this code? What is it hooked too? Please add more detail.

Comment: The code is on functions.php. You can put any metabox inside the if conditional and it will not work.

Comment: how do you sending data? If you sending data from backend edit page then your should use `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`

Comment: An answer was given and it not solves the issue for the lack of details already asked for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`, because when an user saves a post the `POST` request will be send to the server. It means that there is no `$_GET['post']` argument and your meta boxes won't be registered. And if they are not registered, then nothing will be saved.

```
// Only shows for the admin front-page assigned page.
$front_page_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
$post_id = (empty($_REQUEST['post'])) ? NULL : $_REQUEST['post'];

if (is_admin() && $front_page_id == $post_id) {
    ........
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. Nothing were saved.

Comment: Do you have a hook for `save_post` action?

Comment: I tried with the codex example http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box and it didn't work either.

Comment: @Daniel Enable [debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see if anything is going weird!